# Any tips or tricks to improve exponent calculations?

Tags: exponential-function, percentages

I was going through a compound interest question which had the sum be compounded quarterly.
And ultimately I reached this Equation => 5000*((1.03)^12)
Is there any way I could find the answer quickly without using a calculator ?

Comment: There's no equation here.  Do you want to evaluate the expression $5000\cdot1.03^{12}$ without a calculator?  In your head or with pencil and paper?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're interested in doing this calculation without a calculator?

Comment: Not really. It is approximately $5000*(1+12*0.03)=5000+10000*6*0.03 = 5000 + 1800 = 6800$ but only approximately.

Comment: You can quickly estimate it using [rule of 72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72): at 3% interest it takes roughly 72/3=24 periods to double, so after 12 periods it is roughly $\sqrt2$ of the initial amount 5000, or roughly 7100.

Comment: One strategy to get a rough approximation is to truncate the binomial expansion
$$
5000 \cdot (1 + .03)^{12} = 
5000(1 + 12 \cdot .03 + \binom {12}2 (.03)^2 + \cdots + \binom{12}{12}(.03)^{12}).
$$
For example, stopping at the second term gives you $5000 + 12 \cdot 5000 \cdot .03$, which coincides with the simple interest rate. Stopping after 3 terms gives you
$$
5000(1 + 12 \cdot .03 + \binom {12}2 (.03)^2 +  \binom {12}3 (.03)^3 ),
$$
which is about 2.10 away from the true answer.